# How can I determine which font is broken?

Tags: 11.04, fonts, japanese

There's [a bug in the way Ubuntu displays Japanese fonts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anthy/+bug/616159) that I need fixed rather urgently.

The bug is that Ubuntu displays the wrong Japanese characters sometimes.

I'm studying Japanese, and having the wrong characters display is obviously problematic.

However, as you can see if you look at the most recent comments on the bug report, fixing the bug seems stalled on the fact that some specific fonts are probably broken, but I don't know which ones.

Here's what I *think* is happening. If Japanese text is used in a context where the specified font does not contain Japanese characters, then Ubuntu defaults to some other font for the words that are written in Japanese.

However, it is unclear to me what that default Japanese font would be, and how I can determine it.

Is there a way I can determine the default font being used when I see text on my screen that is showing the faulty characters?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: However, this bug is now fixed!

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards: Are you sure? The bug report simply says no activity for over sixy days, and the offered in the bug report was to remove certain fonts, not that those fonts had been fixed.

Comment: Yes, かくれんぼ first-results 隠れん坊 for me with a default font configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: [bug 616169](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anthy/+bug/616159/comments/7) comment made by [martin-autotelic](https://launchpad.net/~martin-autotelic)

Quote:

> I've solved this problem for me.  Following information here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1487447 Basically I removed all Japanese fonts listed as installed in Synaptic, and then installed only these:

```
ttf-kochi-mincho-naga10
ttf-kochi-gothic-naga10
ttf-sazanami-gothic
ttf-sazanami-mincho
```

> Now I am getting the correct kanji consistently. Unfortunately, I do not know which of the fonts I uninstalled was corrupted, as I do not have the time to test and experiment. I will report if I work it out, though.

If you want to exactly know what font is messing up you will have remove all of them and have to start adding fonts one at a time and check if the problems starts to show up (lot of work but if you do please update the bug ;) ) To give you a headstart these fonts in the [ubuntuforums link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9449150&postcount=5) mentioned in the quote have been called not to be the culprits by user Frantic_Earthling:

```
ttf-umeplus
ttf-kochi-mincho-naga10
ttf-kochi-gothic-naga10
ttf-sazanami-gothic
ttf-sazanami-mincho
otf-ipafont-mincho
otf-ipafont-gothic
otf-ipaexfont-gothic
otf-ipaexfont-mincho
anthy
libanthy0
ttf-takao-pgothic
ibus-anthy
libtext-wrapi18n-perl
acroread-fonts
python-chardet
im-switch
```